# How to delete the repeated numbers within a column in a file?

Tags: linux, text

I have a file look like:

input:

```
34
34
34
43
54
54
10001
10001
10001
10001
100005
100005
500000
```

So I need each number appears only once:

OUt:

```
34
43
54
10001
100005
500000
```

any suggestion by considering that real file is huge with too many repetitions?

Comment: `awk '!a[$0]++' file` ? Did you search at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you are:

```
$ uniq inputFile > outputFile
```

But notice `uniq` only removes those repetitive lines coming after each other and sequently. So if you wanted to delete all repetitive lines even those not coming sequently, you can first `sort` your input file and the use `uniq`:

```
$ sort -g inputFile | uniq > outputFile
```

`-g` option will compare according to the general numeric value.

Or just use `sort -nu inputFile > outputFile`

Comment: Note the `$` is just to give the appearance of terminal input. Don't actually type that.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I think everyone knows that, in fact, we use it so people can understand if it's a command which should be put directly into terminal or if it's a command inside a file - for instance bash script or configuration file, which shouldn't have this sign.

Comment: How do they know? Eventually new users will have to be told, work it out for themselves, or read a comment telling them about it.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Affirmative, but new users to this site should have been using terminal for a while, so they know what `#` sign and `$` are representing. Imagine I wanted to put the output of the command below my answer, how could they distinguish if all lines were like the same? Everyone - at least most of us - use `$` to say it's a command used in terminal directly. IF and only IF, the $ is at the beginning of the line, and is not for variables and etc.

Answer (score 2):

You need to sort if you wish to remove duplicates which are not already in consecutive lines, like:

```
cat FILE1 | sort -nu > FILE2
```

`sort -n` means numerical sort and `-u` removes consecutive duplicate lines (like the standalone command `uniq` does on sorted files/data).

Comment: There is no need of `cat`ing the input mate.